# Route specific URL HTTP requests to different URL's on Linux

Tags: networking, ubuntu, google-chrome, proxy, redirection

So you can use the hosts file to redirect hostnames to specific IPs, but what if I want to redirect a specific URL, lets say http://website.com/assets/somescript.js, to a different URL, for example, http://localhost/replacingscript.js. So that whenever I visit a website that requests http://website.com/assets/somescript.js, the browser loads http://localhost/replacingscript.js instead.

Would be great if it would work on Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: use proxy server

Comment: can you elaborate or suggest anything specific? I tried googling about this, but didn't really get how to do it

Comment: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors